# Let $G_1, G_2$ be groups, $H_1 < G_1, H_2 < G_2$ and $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ an isomorphism with $\phi(H_1) = H_2$. Prove that $[G_1 : H_1] = [G_2 : H_2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

The problem statement is:

> Suppose $G_1, G_2$ are groups and $H_1 < G_1, H_2 < G_2$ and $\phi: G_1 \to G_2$ an isomorphism with $\phi(H_1) = H_2$ Prove that $[G_1 : H_1] = [G_2 : H_2]$

So, for this problem I can do it in the case that $G_1, G_2$ finite (since it's almost trivial)

> Since $\phi$ an isomorphism then we know $\lvert G_1 \rvert = \lvert G_2 \rvert$ and since the image of $H_1$ is all of $H_2$ then it must be the case that $\lvert H_1 \rvert = \lvert H_2 \rvert$. Thus, by Lagrange's Theorem $$[G_1:H_1] = \frac{\lvert G_1 \rvert}{\lvert H_1 \rvert} = \frac{\lvert G_2 \rvert}{\lvert H_2 \rvert} = [G_2 : H_2]$$

However the general case where either group is infinite is where I'm having trouble. Since we can't appeal to Lagranges Theorem, as well the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism does not necessarily mean that $\lvert G_1 \rvert = \lvert G_2 \rvert$. Does the fact that $\phi(H_1) = H_2$ imply that $\lvert H_1 \rvert = \lvert H_2 \rvert$ in this case though? What exactly should I be thinking about to get moving in the right direction? I know this question is asking if there's an isomorphism between $2$ general groups each with subgroup such that the image of one subgroup under the isomorphism is exactly the other subgroup then the number of left cosets of $H_i$ in $G_i$ for $i = 1,2$ must be equal.

The only other piece of information that could be useful that comes to mind is the fact that $G_i/H_i$ is a partition of $G_i$. Hence, for example for $G_1$ we know that

- $\forall g_i, g_k \in G_1\ \text{either}\ g_iH_1 = g_kH_1\ \text{or}\ g_iH_1 \cap g_kH_1 = \emptyset$
- $\bigcup_{g_iH_1 \in G_1/H_1} g_iH_1 = G_1$

But not sure how to proceed.

Comment: $\phi$ induces a bijection $G_1/H_1\to G_2/H_2$. That is, $\phi(gH_1)=\phi(g)\phi(H_1)=\phi(g)H_2$ is well-defined.

Comment: But $H_1,H_2$ need not be normal in their respective groups, @runway44; the quotient groups are not always defined.

Comment: @Shaun I never said anything about quotient groups. They're quotient sets, i.e. coset spaces.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see; I'm sorry, @runway44 :)

Comment: Why do you think "the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism does not necessarily mean that $|G_1| = |G_2|$"? An isomorphism is, by definition, a bijection

Comment: Note I do not think the fact that $|G_1| = |G_2|$ or $|H_1| = |H_2|$ (which is also true) will help you, as you can't divide infinite cardinals. you will have to follow runway's comment